# phpexcel generating xls with no compatibility

Tags: compatibility, phpexcel, xls

I'm using PHPexcel to open, edit, save and download edited xls. After that i'm using the xls to import some data in my tool(doesn't matter the tool), but my tool is telling me that cannot find sheet with name specific name, but is there.

All i need to do, is to open the file with microsoft office excel, and just save again with ctrl+s without any modification(this shouldn't be possible). After opening and saving file with office excel, size of file is lower and the compatibility with my tool is restored.

What i can do to save file directly in the correct format?

I'm saving file with next code:

```
 $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($objPHPExcel);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$_FILES["file"]["name"].'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$objWriter->save('test.xls');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: You say `it doesn't matter the tool`? Clearly it does matter! The file generated by PHPExcel can be opened without problem by MS Excel; but the `tool` can't load it successfully. Sounds like a problem with the `tool`

Comment: Hy. Thank you for answer. I said that doesn't matter the tool because i suppose that almost all tools which need to import xls, will have the same problem with phpexcel xls. Is there any posibility to save xls from php with 100% compatibility, like the xls saved by Microsoft Office?

Comment: If 100% compatibility could be guaranteed (without big costs in performance and memory), don't you think I'd be doing it already in PHPExcel? Yes, PHPExcel takes a couple of of shortcuts when savibg, so that (for example) it doesn't rationalise all styles that are identical: that would take extra time to compare every style against every other style and eliminate duplicates, but it would reduce the size of the generated file....

Comment: however, PHPExcel does produce a file that conforms with the published MS Excel format-specifications, so any other application that works with those specifications should be capable of reading that file

Comment: yes, i think that's the problem. The files are generated conforms with the published MS Excel format-specification, and many tools need "original" xls format. This is what i understand. Thank you